# How to ignore ignore spacing, capitalization, and punctuation

Tags: javascript

I have written this code and tried to use regex global to check with no luck.

```js
  
let numberOfOccurrences = (str) => {
  let charObject = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if ( charObject [str[i]]) {
      charObject [str[i]] += 1;
      console.log(charObject)
    } else {
      charObject [str[i]] = 1;
      console.log (charObject)
    }
  }
  return charObject;
}

numberOfOccurrences('aaabbc')
```

I am trying to have the function read strings and return the count of each character but ignore capital letters and special characters

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please be [more descriptive](/help/how-to-ask) in your post. Explain what you tried to do (missing), show what you did (already in the post), what it did instead (missing) and what you already tried to figure out why (missing).

Comment: To ignore capitalization, convert the character to lowercase before searching for it in `charObject`.

Comment: I am trying to have the function read strings and return the count of each character but ignore all capital letters and special characters. and not count them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
let numberOfOccurrences = (str) => {
  let charObject = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (!str[i].match(/^[a-z]+$/)) continue;
    if (!charObject[str[i]]) charObject[str[i]] = 0;
    charObject [str[i]] += 1;         
  }
  console.log(charObject)
  return charObject;
}

numberOfOccurrences('Aaaabb c#$2')
```

This will ignore all characters except lowercase letters